# How to parse JSON in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am using the following code

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.v_modalLink').click(function(){
        var journalId=$(this).attr('data-id');
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"<?php echo base_url();?>index.php/pranasInventory/view_invoice/1",
            data:{journalId:journalId},
            success:function(data)
            {
                var json_obj=$.parseJSON(data);
                for(var i in json_obj)
                {
                    voucherId=json_obj[i].invoice_id;

                }

            }
        });
    })
});
</script>
```

I want to assign the each responce value in each variable Ex:clientName="dxx";cleitPhone="eerere"

I have the following console response:

```
{
    "invoice": [{
        "invoice_id": "1",
        "client_id": "1",
        "client_name": "makemytrip",
        "client_phone": "1234567891",
        "client_email": "info@makemytrip.com",
        "client_address": "Banglore.",
        "service_name": "Mobile   Apps",
        "service_description": "asdasd asasd  asdads asdasdads.",
        "created_date": "2016-08-10",
        "gross_amount": "1000000",
        "tax_amount": "145000",
        "net_amount": "1145000",
        "tax_identifier_name": "Service Tax 14.5%"
    }],
    "myarray": [{
        "taxname": "Service tax @ 14%",
        "taxamount": 140000
    }, {
        "taxname": "swachh bharat cess @  0.5%",
        "taxamount": 5000
    }],
    "rowcount": 2
}
```

How can I parse the above data in jQuery? Thanks.

Comment: Unclear. Please [edit] to add description, example and other details.

Comment: It appears as though it already is parsed...? Assuming what you've posted is actually a string, send it as a parameter to `JSON.parse()`. Note that if you retrieve this JSON through an AJAX request then it will be automatically parsed for you by jQuery - assuming you've set the correct MIME type in the response

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your success response to

```
success:function(data)
{
    var json_obj = JSON.parse(data);

    var voucherId = json_obj['invoice'][0].invoice_id;
    var clientName = json_obj['invoice'][0].client_name;
    var clientPhone = json_obj['invoice'][0].client_phone;

    //myarray

    var taxName1 = json_obj['myarray'][0].taxname;
    var taxAmount1 = json_obj['myarray'][0].taxamount;
    var taxName2 = json_obj['myarray'][1].taxname;
    var taxAmount2 = json_obj['myarray'][1].taxamount;

    //rowcount

    var rowCount = json_obj.rowcount;
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir,its working.but how get second array value i mean taxname,taxamount in myarray

Comment: Edited my answer, please check and let me know if this is working or not.

Answer (score 0):

Set response to variable and use the variable in your jQuery method.